# Understanding basics of controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm still very basic with AngularJS (and programming in general honestly speaking. Having watched some videos online, I'm trying to understand the controller concept with the below example (e.g. passing an array and then iterating through it with ng-repeat). Have gone over this for the past hour and it works without the controller (e.g. with the array), but not when adding the array in a seperate script. Can anyone help me find my error in logic here - it literally is the same as the video, but I cannot see the error (or even a typo) and feel this is so fundamental, I should have this working, before moving on to the next steps.

Many thanks for any of your help:

```
<html ng-app>
<head><title>My First Page</title></head>
<body >
<div class="container" ng-controller="SimpleController">
    Name:
    <br />
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
    <br />    
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="cust in customers"> {{ cust.name }} </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script src="script/angular.min.js"></script> 
<script>
    function SimpleController($scope) {
$scope.customers = [
    { name: 'Simon', lastname: 'Test' },
    { name: 'Thomas', lastname: 'Testi' },
    { name: 'Adi', lastname: 'Testo' },
    { name: 'Adrian', lastname: 'Testo' },
    { name: 'Tomeli', lastname: 'Testi' }
];
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using global declaration of controller which is with angular 1.1 version. If you use version above 1.3 , you should declare the controller as follows,

```
var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.customers = [
    { name: 'Simon', lastname: 'Test' },
    { name: 'Thomas', lastname: 'Testi' },
    { name: 'Adi', lastname: 'Testo' },
    { name: 'Adrian', lastname: 'Testo' },
    { name: 'Tomeli', lastname: 'Testi' }
];
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('SimpleController',function($scope){
  $scope.customers = [
    { name: 'Simon', lastname: 'Test' },
    { name: 'Thomas', lastname: 'Testi' },
    { name: 'Adi', lastname: 'Testo' },
    { name: 'Adrian', lastname: 'Testo' },
    { name: 'Tomeli', lastname: 'Testi' }
];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp">
 <div class="container" ng-controller="SimpleController">
    Name:
    <br />
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
    <br />    
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="cust in customers"> {{ cust.name }} </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why thank you Sajeetharan, that works perfectly and honestly, would never have found that since the video did not yet list the 2 versions.. it actually works perfectly, when I download the legacy version of AngularJS. Now to understand the changes:-) Thanks once more, Simon

Comment: you're welcome!  good luck with your learning! Personally i would suggest you to start with angular6 , because angularjs is outdated